# Два и более меню в одной activity

Tags: android

Как добавить два и более меню в одну activity в программировании под Android?

Допустим мы хотим добавить верхнее меню (три вертикальные точки с шапке с именем приложения), что не составит труда даже у новичков, и внешне такое же меню, как в **Navigation Drawer Activity**, только не выдвижное, а статическое, отображающееся всегда (грубо смонтировал изображение конечного результата):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Если вотнкуть ещё одно меню в `onCreateOptionsMenu`, тогда просто получится одно меню с элементами из обоих:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
      return true;
  }
  ```
- Два метода `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` быть естественно не может.

---

Обновление: вот примерно то, что я хочу сделать (на язык не обращайте внимания; для ответа подойдёт любая "рыба", хоть традиционный lorem ipsum). Красным обозначено верхнее выпадающее меню, а на любое из полей, которое я обозначил фиолетовым, можно нажимать и оно перебросит на другую активность. Почти набор кнопок, только каждая кнопка имеет большую иконку, маленькую иконку и две надписи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: способов решения вашей проблемы уйма, можно просто сделать submenu, можно рядом сделать у меню иконку при нажатии будет вызываться PopUp.
Можно добавить ещё ToolBar и раздуть его ещё меню, будет тоже два меню, ну или сколько вам надо, вы уточните что вам нужно.

Comment: Уточняю. С верхним меню я разобрался; его можно не трогать. Второе меню - по сути самый обычный экран настроек. Как его реализовывать - особого значения не имеет, главное чтобы его можно было также легко запрограммировать, как верхнее меню. Шаблон с экраном настроек я смотрел - наверно, можно использовать, но хотелось бы поменьше кода, чем в том шаблоне.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, ну, думаю, вас должно устроить решение через NavigationView, чрез кое делается NavigationDrawer

Comment: Сегодня долго изучал код этого шаблона, но мне пока как новичку не понятно, как изменить код метода onCreate() таким образом, чтобы вместо выдвижного меню было статичное меню (аналог экрана настроек)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu а почему просто не сверстать обычный экран, такой как у вас на картинке без NavigationDrawer если вам не нужно что бы его можно было свайпать?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, пользоваться шаблонами студии не стоит. Они либо слишком сложны для новичков или слишком негибки для остальных. Чтобы NavigationView не был спрятан слева, его надо в разметке оставить единственным элементов разметки и убрать атрибут gravity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В Activity более одного меню сделать нельзя. Я могу предложить Вам немного другой вариант.

Создаём две кнопки в ActionBar. **Файл i1.xml**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.example.I1" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/action_menu1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/action_menu2"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Вот так это будет выглядеть в итоге:

[image: 1]

Эти кнопки будут выступать в роли кнопки меню. Вот код Activity. **Файл I1.java**

```
package com.example.example;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class I1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] i1 = new String[]{"Первый пункт", "Второй пункт", "Третий пункт"};
    private String[] i2 = new String[]{"Пункт А", "Пункт Б"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle i1) {
        super.onCreate(i1);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_i1);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu i1) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.i1, i1);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem i1) {
        AlertDialog.Builder i2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        i2.setCancelable(true);
        switch (i1.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_menu1:
            i2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            i2.setTitle(getString(R.string.action_menu1));
            i2.setItems(this.i1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface i1, int i2) {
                    i1.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(I1.this, "Выбран пункт:" + "\n" + I1.this.i1[i2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

            });
            break;
        case R.id.action_menu2:
            i2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            i2.setTitle(getString(R.string.action_menu2));
            i2.setItems(this.i2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface i1, int i2) {
                    i1.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(I1.this, "Выбран пункт:" + "\n" + I1.this.i2[i2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

            });
            break;
        }
        i2.create().show();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(i1);
    }

}
```

При нажатии на них открывается лист `AlertDialog` с пунктами. Пользователь просто выбирает нужный ему пункт.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

---

Для того, чтобы сделать круглую плавающую кнопку внизу Activity, как на картинке

[image: 4]

необходимо создать новый класс под названием `FloatingActionButton`, вставить в него этот код:

```
package com.example.example;

import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.OvershootInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class FloatingActionButton extends View {

    final static OvershootInterpolator overshootInterpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
    final static AccelerateInterpolator accelerateInterpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();

    Context context;
    Paint mButtonPaint;
    Paint mDrawablePaint;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    boolean mHidden = false;

    public FloatingActionButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void setFloatingActionButtonColor(int FloatingActionButtonColor) {
        init(FloatingActionButtonColor);
    }

    public void setFloatingActionButtonDrawable(Drawable FloatingActionButtonDrawable) {
        mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) FloatingActionButtonDrawable).getBitmap();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void init(int FloatingActionButtonColor) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mButtonPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mButtonPaint.setColor(FloatingActionButtonColor);
        mButtonPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mButtonPaint.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 3.5f, Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
        mDrawablePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        setClickable(true);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, (float) (getWidth() / 2.6), mButtonPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (getWidth() - mBitmap.getWidth()) / 2, (getHeight() - mBitmap.getHeight()) / 2, mDrawablePaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            setAlpha(1.0f);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            setAlpha(0.6f);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void hideFloatingActionButton() {
        if (!mHidden) {
            ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 1, 0);
            ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 1, 0);
            AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
            animSetXY.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
            animSetXY.setInterpolator(accelerateInterpolator);
            animSetXY.setDuration(100);
            animSetXY.start();
            mHidden = true;
        }
    }

    public void showFloatingActionButton() {
        if (mHidden) {
            ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 0, 1);
            ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 0, 1);
            AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
            animSetXY.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
            animSetXY.setInterpolator(overshootInterpolator);
            animSetXY.setDuration(200);
            animSetXY.start();
            mHidden = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isHidden() {
        return mHidden;
    }

    static public class Builder {
        private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
        private final Activity activity;
        int gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT; // default bottom right
        Drawable drawable;
        int color = Color.WHITE;
        int size = 0;
        float scale = 0;
        public Builder(Activity context) {
            scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            size = convertToPixels(72, scale); // default size is 72dp by 72dp
            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
            params.gravity = gravity;
            this.activity = context;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the gravity for the FAB
         */
        public Builder withGravity(int gravity) {
            this.gravity = gravity;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the margins for the FAB in dp
         */
        public Builder withMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            params.setMargins(
                    convertToPixels(left, scale),
                    convertToPixels(top, scale),
                    convertToPixels(right, scale),
                    convertToPixels(bottom, scale));
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the FAB drawable
         */
        public Builder withDrawable(final Drawable drawable) {
            this.drawable = drawable;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the FAB color
         */
        public Builder withButtonColor(final int color) {
            this.color = color;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the FAB size in dp
         */
        public Builder withButtonSize(int size) {
            size = convertToPixels(size, scale);
            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
            return this;
        }

        public FloatingActionButton create() {
            final FloatingActionButton button = new FloatingActionButton(activity);
            button.setFloatingActionButtonColor(this.color);
            button.setFloatingActionButtonDrawable(this.drawable);
            params.gravity = this.gravity;
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            root.addView(button, params);
            return button;
        }

        // The calculation (value * scale + 0.5f) is a widely used to convert to dps to pixel units
        // based on density scale
        // see developer.android.com (Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes)
        private int convertToPixels(int dp, float scale) {
            return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f) ;
        }

    }
}
```

и затем, в метод `onCreate()` твоего Activity вставить этот код:

```
FloatingActionButton i2 = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
    .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_add)) // картинка твоей кнопки
    .withButtonColor(Color.RED) // красный цвет
    .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT) // расположение справа снизу
    .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16) // некоторый отступ
    .create();
```

Это один из лучших и удобных вариантов, поэтому, к сожалению, так много кода.

---

Чтобы сделать кнопку, которую Вы обвели в своём вопросе на последнем скриншоте фиолетовой рамкой, нужно дописать следующий код в XML Layout твоего Activity:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/i1_LinearLayout_myButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/моя_большая_картинка" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/моя_маленькая_картинка"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18pt"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="*1,560" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="**********" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

и этот код в метод `onCreate()` твоего Activity:

```
LinearLayout i3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.i1_LinearLayout_myButton);
i3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View i1) {
        startActivity(...); // и тут код запуска новой Activity
        return;
    }

});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за потраченное время! Я вручу приз примерно за день до закрытия конкурса. Скажите новичку, а как тогда экран настроек реализован в шаблоне Android Studio? Насколько я видел, там тоже есть верхнее меню, но основной экран также выполняет роль меню. Я добавил в вопрос пример приложения, где есть главное и верхнее меню.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, я использую Eclipse Android вместо Android Studio. Не совсем понял, что конкретно у Вас не получается. Не отображается та синяя круглая кнопка внизу Activity?

Comment: Нет. Вообщем я добавил в вопрос то, что хочу сделать в итоге. У меня на данный момент не хватает знаний чтобы, сделать набор кнопок-полей, одно из которых я обозначил фиолетовым.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, через час освобожусь - напишу. Многовато кода получится.

Comment: Верхнее меню можете не вставлять - я уже умею это делать. Добавьте пожлалуйста две "фиолетовые" кнопки, каждая с иконкой и двумя заголовками. Запрограммировать можно только одну (чтобы я понял принцип) - она должна отправить в другую, пустую активность.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, https://hsto.org/files/3e2/fe8/cc9/3e2fe8cc97094772a31919b85e6c4fb0.png это нужно? Левая картинка. Правильно понял? Или это https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/6b0/504/c8c/6b0504c8c6c912eece0b220e1b027d6a.png фиолетового цвета?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, про плавающую кнопку дописал в ответе, как её сделать. Если нужны вкладки (первая ссылка моего предыдущего комментария), могу дописать. Там, конечно, немного посложнее :D и кода раза в два может быть побольше.

Comment: Первое нужно было :) Да, левая картинка. С плавающей кнопкой всё просто, она есть в пресетах Android Studio. Неимоверно жалко Ваше время (учитывая Ваше профессионализм), что Вас на эту плавающую кнопку потянуло... Сделайте пожалуйста кнопку, которую обвёл в СИРЕНЕВУЮ рамку в последней картинке своего вопроса (с надписями на любом понятном для Вас языке), и на этом забирайте Ваш приз! :) Эта кнопка должна открывать новую активность.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, времени до сентября уйма. Потом проекты свои пойдут. Сейчас я сделаю эту Вашу волшебную кнопку.. :D

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, готово.

Comment: Отлично, благодарю Вас за код! Как и обещал, отдаю Вам приз в 50 репутации!